# Determining the distance of linear code using parity-check matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, matrix-rank, coding-theory

A matrix $H$ over $\Bbb F_2$ has as the first seven rows $I_7$ and the other rows are all of the vectors of $\{0,1\}^7$ with exactly three $1$'s per vector (weight-$3$ vectors). I know that this can be a [parity-check matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity-check_matrix) for a [linear code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_code) $C$. I want to find the distance $d(C)$ for this linear code, which can be computed by determining the number of linearly independent rows of $H$. So this comes down to simply finding the rank of $H$.

I think rank$(H)=7$ because the RREF of $H$ just gives the matrix with rows $I_7$ and the rest are zero rows. So the $d(C) = \operatorname{rank}(H)+1=8$. The correction manual says $4$. I don't know how this is possible. Is my formula for the distance of a code wrong? It just comes down to determining the amount of lin independent rows of $H$, which I think should be $7$.

Edit: I think I read the theorem about the distance of a linear code $C$ wrong. The distance is $d$ when ANY set of $d-1$ rows of $H$ is lin indep and there is a set of $d$ rows of $H$ that is linearly dependent. That may be different from the rank of $H$?

Comment: The edit is indeed the key: the (row) rank of a matrix is the maximum number of linearly *independent* rows, whereas the quantity we compute for the distance of a code is instead the minimum number of rows that are linearly *dependent*.

Comment: To see that these are vastly different quantities, consider a simple example of two identity matrices glued together. This doesn't change the rank from just one copy of the identity matrix, since the row space is exactly the same as before, but it does change the distance since you can now find two linearly dependent (in fact equal) rows.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the rank and the quantity determining the minimum distance are distinct.

If any set of $d-1$ rows are linearly independent that means that no parity check of weight $d-1$ exists that gives zero. Thus no codeword of weight $\leq d-1$ exists. On the other hand if a set of $d$ rows are linearly dependent this implies that there is at least one codeword of weight $d.$ To see this let there be a minimal parity check of weight $d$ with support set $J=\{j_1,j_2,\ldots,j_d\} \subset \{1,\ldots,n\}.$ Then the word $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ with $$x_i=1 \Leftrightarrow i \in J$$
is a minimum weight codeword in this code. No codeword of smaller weight exists other than the all zero codeword. Since the code is linear, the componentwise sum (same as difference in $\mathbb{F}_2$) of any two codewords is also a codeword. Thus the minimum distance of the code is $d.$